# If today is 06/09/2017 then what is: first day of month that is 12 months earlier than prior month in teradata?

Tags: database, datetime, casting, teradata, type-conversion

This is working but I want the output of this query as a date, but I'm unable to cast it.

```
Select (EXTRACT(Year FROM date) - 1) || (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) - 1) || EXTRACT(DAY from (date - ((EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) )) + 1))
```

Its output is a string, I suppose. Please help me casting it in date.

Answer (score 2):

Your current logic will fail in January.

This returns the first day 13 months ago:

```
trunc(add_months(dt,-13),'mon')
```